# jsbin error ES6 examples

Tags: javascript, jsbin

I was trying to run the Javascript in JSBin for the first time as in screenshot below 
 [image: Jsbin image]

why the console is not showing the result as expected any suggestions

Thanks 
Prasad

Comment: If you had checked the console of your browser you would have seen the problem: `Filter !== filter`

Comment: Thanks for the error finding . thought that the console shown and browser console will be same as I am new to JSbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f should be small in filter.

.

Comment: Since when is `Array.prototype.filter()` part of ES6? O.o `.filter()` is part of [ECMAScript 5.1 from 2011](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20)